# Change the Coordinate System for Unity Export?

Tags: unity, coordinates, axis

How to change the axis Z and Y? Make it so that it was like in Unity or maybe this can be done in Unity?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do it in these softwares, but you can adjust the axes in the export menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just model in blender the way it is intended. Before you export your model to unity you can adjust the export settings in the export dialog, there you can switch the axes around however you like.